# How do you inject impl of some interface in an Android Activity using Guice

Tags: java, android, guice, roboguice

I'm using Guice 3.0 on Android to do some DI.

I have

```
public interface APIClient { }
```

and

```
public class DefaultAPIClient implements APIClient { }
```

What I did was try to bootstrap Guice in my MyApplication class giving it a module that has one statement in the configure method `bind(APIClient.class).to(DefaultAPIClient.class);`

I did what the Guice example told me to do

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new APIClientModule());
injector.getInstance(APIClient.class);
```

I may not be understanding this correctly, but how would I go about injecting APIClient into several Activities that will use it?

I did this in `HomeActivity`

```
public class HomeActivity extends RoboActivity {
    @Inject APIClient client;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        client.doSomething();
    }
}
```

This doesn't work and it gives me the `Guice configuration errors: 1) No implementation for com.mycompany.APIClient was bound`

So the only way I was able to get this to work was to remove the `@Inject` from the APIClient client in HomeActivity and inject it using `client = Guice.createInjector(new APIClientModule()).getInstance(APIClient.class);`

So does this mean that I'll have to do this in every Activity that uses APIClient? I must be doing something wrong.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Roboguice 2.0 with Guice 3.0_noaop, the way to define additional custom modules is through the string-array resource file roboguice_modules:

from the docs ([Upgradingto20](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/UpgradingTo20)):

> It's no longer necessary/possible to inherit from RoboApplication any more since that class is gone. If you wish to override the default RoboGuice bindings, you may specify a custom module classname in a string-array resource called "roboguice_modules" in res/values/roboguice.xml. eg.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources> 
    <string-array name="roboguice_modules">
        <item>PACKAGE.APIClientModule</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

So you will need to define your custom module as follows:

roboguice_modules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources> 
    <string-array name="roboguice_modules">
        <item>DONT_KNOW_YOUR_PACKAGE.APIClientModule</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

with a binding between APIClient and DefaultAPIClient of course.

and Roboguice should do the rest.

Comment: I did come across that when I was researching. Is there a way to do this programmatically instead of in the XML? I can go and trace through the code, but just figured I'd ask if you had a quick answer. Thanks

Comment: There is simply no way to configure roboguice custom modules in plain old java without modifying roboguice. Here's the code that looks up the modules you define: http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/source/browse/roboguice/src/main/java/roboguice/RoboGuice.java lines 101+

Comment: Check out RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector(...) to programmatically set your modules in 2.0.  You'll want to call it once for your app, so you can use a static initializer or call it from a custom application class.  http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/source/browse/roboguice/src/main/java/roboguice/RoboGuice.java

Comment: I stand corrected, should have scrolled up a bit ;-)... would you define this in an overridden Application then or is there a better place to define this?

Answer (score 4):

So many thanks to Michael Burton of Groupon for answering this on the [Roboguice mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/roboguice/xEgEYkW1WfM). For anyone interested, here is how to do this programmatically.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector(this, RoboGuice.DEFAULT_STAGE, Modules.override(RoboGuice.newDefaultRoboModule(this)).with(new MyCustomModule()));
    }
}
```

Now I can properly inject `@Inject private APIClient client` in the Activity.

Answer (score -1):

You should use [Guice 2.0(no aop)](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/downloads/detail?name=guice-2.0-no_aop.jar) instead of Guice 3.0

To configure Guice properly you need to override `addApplicationModules(List<Module> modules)` method in your application class and add your module there.

```
public class MyApplication extends RoboApplication {
  @Override
  protected void addApplicationModules(List<Module> modules) {
    modules.add(new YourModule());
  }
```

To use injections in your activities you need to call `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`
because members are injected in `onCreate` method of RoboActivity.

```
public class HomeActivity extends RoboActivity {
    @Inject APIClient client;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Call this before use injected members
        client.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah. The reason I'm using Guice 3.0 is because Roboguice 1.2 now has support for Guice 3. RoboApplication has been deprecated and it now doesn't need the addApplicationModules call. Of course that's only if you don't have custom modules. In my case I do so I looked it up and you have to add modules in roboguice.xml, but I'm looking for a java-way of doing this and try to stay away from xml as much as possible. If you have any idea on adding custom modules in java, let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Oh sorry. I meant I'm using roboguice 2.0b3 not 1.2